# Site for collaborative critiquing for web usability of websites?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design

I like [conceptfeedback.com](http://conceptfeedback.com) where users post their opinions about a webpage. However the critiques are mainly about a page's layout and visual design. Are there similar sites where critiques go beyond a page's layout. For example giving feedback about the Javascript interaction, form elements and validation, proper use of certain types of UI elements for displaying certain data (dropdown in place of radiobuttons for example), clicking, hovering, lightboxes, proper use of AJAX, performance,..etc. Stuff which go beyond layout, fonts, text size, colors, alignment.. etc which are typically mentioned at conceptfeedback.com

Comment: So is it conceptfeedback.com or feedbackconcept.com :)

Comment: @Denzo it's conceptfeedback. The original post had feedbackconcept which doesn't exist. I fixed the link but didn't notice the second occurrence.

Comment: actually I find a great deal of usability critique on this site. Maybe not on all reviews but on some.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for isn't a feedback website where the person doing the reviewing only really has access to a screenshot or something similar and can therefore only really review that, but a full-on performance, usability, design and accessibility expert review. I doubt you'll find a site where people are willing to do that for prices like $99 (which is what conceptfeedback charges for 1 expert's feedback). For comparison, my company charges hourly rates and expert reviews usually take 2 days of work (at least), so that could easily cost several thousand USD.

Perhaps you should adjust your expectations, or hire someone to give you professional, in-depth feedback :-)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a commercial website which requires people to give full feedbacks. It could be tidbits or comments from several users. Cumulatively the site owner gets some good feedback. I gave small feedback at conceptfeedback.com. I didn't receive a cent and I wasn't expecting any. It doesn't have to be a fullblown site either like conceptfeedback.com. I am not looking for a reviewer for a website for myself. I just want to read other people's feedback or sites they reviewed.. like what I do at conceptfeedback.com.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [uTest,](http://www.utest.com/what-we-test/web-application-testing) which claims to offer usability feedback from 'professional' testers.

You may also consider sites such as [userlytics](http://www.userlytics.com/) and [usertesting.com](http://www.usertesting.com/), although, as ever, the results you get from crowd-sourced usability testing will be determined by the questions you ask, the types of tests you compose, and the demographics you pick.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rahul, you can't really find that support in a website because the things you want to check align very much to usability issues which can't be measured properly by an algorithm. 
Decision about when to use drop-down and when to use radio button have to be decided by case in addition to the partially technical feedback you need you should consult a usability expert with technical background to make an expert review of your website. If you want to do it on your own and want to structure the way you evaluate, you could have a look at the ISO 9241-110 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9241#ISO_9241-110. On part of it is for example, to ensure conformity with user expectations.

Comment: It's feedback from humans. I am not sure why you're mentioning algorithms. conceptfeedback.com doesn't use algorithms. I am not after automated processes. The whole process can be informal. No need to pay hundreds or thousands for a usability expert. That's the point of finding such a site. As for the case by case argument, the feedback is about the webpage being posted. You look at a webpage and say something like "The use of a dropdownlist here with two elements only can be replaced by two radio buttons". A reviewer brings up the issues which need fixing. It's as simple as that.